# onShutter first picture shutter lag is slower than subsequent shots

Tags: android, performance, android-ndk, android-camera

I've run across this peculiar "feature" using my HTC One and the ShutterCallback for the Android Camera (I'll try to get my hands on other devices to see if this is repeatable on other hardware). For the record, I'm not focusing, I've locked the exposure, turned off antibanding, and set the JPEG qaulity to 100.

The first time I take a picture and measure the delay from when takePicture is called to when onShutter is called, the delay is consistently around 850 +/- 50 milliseconds. However, after the first picture, the shutter lag for subsequent pictures becomes around 530 +/- 50 milliseconds. Any thoughts what might be causing this? I've tried looking through the [JNI documentation](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_hardware_Camera.cpp#get_native_camera), but nothing stands out. I wonder if there is some cache in the camera hardware that points to a buffer. However, I don't see why it would make a difference of 300 milliseconds.

EDIT: I see a gap of about 150 for the shutter lag between the first picture and subsequent pictures on a Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: I have done some peculiar things with controlling Android hardware via software.  I noticed that HTC is very weird compared to other OEMs.  Good luck finding a solution, I definitely know this frustration.